# Does an HTTPS connection hide activity from the server?

Tags: logging, ssl, https

Basically, what I am curious about is if the server itself can show contents of the SSL session in logs. So, even though the communication is encrypted bi-directionally, does the server itself log any specific data about that session?

I'm going to use just a real basic example here: Let's say a user on a website is using HTTPS, and they click an image to expand it or open it in a new window, does the "GET" request show in the logs on the receiving server even though the contents (image) is encrypted?

More specifically, exactly what type of activity can be seen from the servers end?

Comment: The server is the one _answering_ the request.  By definition, it can see the request and response.

Comment: Not programming related. Please ask at SuperUser or ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes the server can see what is being requested.

The server will be processing the request. As such it will be decrypting the communication and then acting on the request just as if the request was over HTTP. Now as for what is logged, that is entirely up to the servers config, but again it could log the ~same information for HTTPS and HTTP.

There are subtle differences as to what kind of logging would happen on the HTTPS communication itself based on the setup of the server(s), but I think that would fall out of scope for this question.